# Kotlin App Crash if back button pressed during fetching API

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So i have the problem that the App will crash if the Back button is pressed during fetching service in a fragment. Currently I'm using Retrofit Library to do the service calling tasks. Below is the code snippet of the fragment :

**ProductStockOutletListFragment.kt**

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Product List"

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_product_stock_outlet_list, container, false)

    //Show Progressbar While loading data
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    //Apply layout manager
    binding.rvOutletList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager((activity as AppCompatActivity))

    NetworkConfig().getOutletListService()
        .getOutlets()
        .enqueue(object : Callback<OutletListPOJODataClasses> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<OutletListPOJODataClasses>, t: Throwable) {

                if(call.isCanceled){
                    Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Request Aborted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<OutletListPOJODataClasses>,
                response: Response<OutletListPOJODataClasses>
            ) {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.rvOutletList.adapter = response.body()?.let { OutletListAdapter(it, this@ProductStockOutletListFragment) }

                Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Data retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() //It points out this line. This is where the error happened.
            }

        })

    // Declare that this fragment has menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    // Set action bar title to "Outlet List"
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Outlet List"

    return binding.root
}
```

If back button is pressed, it'll crash and return the error

> kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

The error pointed out at the below line at `OnResponse()`

> Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Data retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Am I missing something ? Or maybe this is a lifecycle-related problem ? Let me know if there's anything Unclear.

Edit : As requested, This is the full error log.
[image]

Comment: Please add full error log.

Comment: @digiwizkid there you go.

Comment: use requireActivity() instead of (activity as AppCompatActivity)

Comment: @ShivamKumar that's just going to cause a different error. `requireActivity()` just throws an `IllegalStateException` in case `getActivity()` returns null. As @Antonio has pointed out in his answer it's due to the network request being resolved later; when the activity object is no longer there; hence getting null. His solution may work but what the OP should do is cancel any pending requests on the onDestroy lifecycle call

Comment: Alternatively I would _HIGHLY_ suggest you liberate that logic from the activity/fragment and just put it into a `VIewModel` and having the fragment/activity observing it through a `LiveData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is because the `activity` you used in Toast becomes null when you backpress (fragment is destroyed) but the api response is received later and toast is executed.

So just add a null check before toasting:

```
if(activity!=null){
    Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Data retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!. This is the best solution for now

Answer (score 0):

You should only handle the response in your Fragment if your fragment is `isAdded`.

Answer (score 0):

When you exit the activity, context is `null` 
your can use `applicationContext`

```
  Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Data retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```